# .htaccess - Remove one query parameter from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, parameters, stage

I have a URL that looks something like this:

```
https://www.example.com/about-us?stage=Stage&utm_source=abc&utm_medium=xyz
```

I want to just remove the stage=Stage part.

I tried the below code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^stage=Stage$
RewriteRule (.*) $Stage? [R=permanent]
```

but it only seems to work if the URL is:

```
https://www.example.com/about-us?stage=Stage
```

without the rest of the parameters.

How can I make the other parameters pass over apart from the stage=Stage parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule at the top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?stage=Stage(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much!